# How do I align 3 dataframes diagonally in a larger dataframe such that the remaining values are empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes that hold numbers from 1 to 9. I want to create a larger dataframe that consists of these 3 dataframes aligned diagonally. The dataframes are as below.

```
df_gr1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 4, 7], [1, 9, 6], [2, 8, 3]])
df_gr2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[3, 2, 7], [5, 1, 8], [4, 9, 6]])
df_gr3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[2, 3, 9], [8, 5, 6], [7, 1, 4]])
```

`display(df_gr1)`  Output-> [df_gr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHgvv.png)

`display(df_gr2)`  Output-> [df_gr2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFJpb.png)

`display(df_gr3)`  Output-> [df_gr3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM1ab.png)

The Final DataFrame that I am looking for is something like this:

| 5 | 4 | 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **9** | **6** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **2** | **8** | **3** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | **3** | **2** | **7** |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | **5** | **1** | **8** |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | **4** | **9** | **6** |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | **2** | **3** | **9** |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | **8** | **5** | **6** |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | **7** | **1** | **4** |

I plan to append values to the empty cells **after** this dataframe is created. But first I need it to be empty.

Hoping for something dynamic.

Thank You

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean by:

```
print(pd.concat([df_gr1, df_gr2.rename(index={0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}), df_gr3.rename(index={0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8})], axis=1).fillna('').T.reset_index(drop=True).T)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  5  4  7                  
1  1  9  6                  
2  2  8  3                  
3           3  2  7         
4           5  1  8         
5           4  9  6         
6                    2  3  9
7                    8  5  6
8                    7  1  4
```

Comment: Note that if you want this to be "dynamic", you just need to do some bookkeeping with respect to where the indexes start and stop. You also might want to just create the DataFrames with suitable `RangeIndex`es in the first place, instead of re-labeling them before `concat`-ing.

Comment: @shadowtalker yeah true, it isn't clear how the OP wants it tho